# Get text Input Value React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to track the text input value using states but "e.target.value" doesn't seem to work(maybe because my component is declared as a function). Is there any other way I can do it?

```
const UncontrolledDiagram = ({ sentence }) => {
  // create diagrams schema

  const [schema, { onChange, addNode, connect, removeNode }] = useSchema(initialSchema);

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const [textInput,setInput]=useState('')
  
  const handleTextChange=(e)=>{
    setInput(e.target.value);
    console.log(textInput);
  }
```

This is the input field I am tracking:

```
const conditionalDisplay=(id)=>{
    const nodeToCheck=schema.nodes.find(node=>node.id=== id);
    if(nodeToCheck.form===null){
      return(
        <div>
          <label>Form: </label><input style={{ width: '25px', height: '12px' }} onChange={handleTextChange} type='text'></input>
          <button className='buttonInputSubmit'>+</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    else{
      return(
        <div style={{display: 'flex',margin: '0'}}>
          <label>Form: </label><p style={{color: 'yellow', marginLeft:'2px'}}>{nodeToCheck.form}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It works, your `console.log(textInput)` still has the old state because state is set asynchronously. It will set the state as soon as your function has been fully executed.

```
const handleTextChange=(e)=>{
   setInput(e.target.value);
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(textInput);
}, [textInput])
```

Comment: that's because you are console logging in a syncronous way.